# WebSocket.onmessage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, django, sockets

I'm using django-channels for implementing sockets in a django app.

I've followed [instructions](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) and it worked:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/");
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("hello world");
}
```

but when I use my own code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/");
        socket.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        };
        $('form').submit(function () {
            socket.send($('form>input[type="text"]').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

My django server receives the message but socket.onmessage is not called. Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding the original code to the ready block is either not working?

```
socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log("socket open")
    socket.send("hello world");
}
```

It could be that the channel is not yet opened

Comment: Nope, socket is opened. All's right. I just wanna to alert message that have been sent to server and returned to client

Comment: If you want to aler the use alert(e.data), otherwise it will just show in the console (press F12 to see it)

Answer (score 0):

That's code that worked

```
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/");
    socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        alert(e.data);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        socket.onopen = function() {
            $('button').click(function () {
                socket.send($('#mes_input').val());
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: this only works first time Only

    socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        alert(e.data);
    };